# starting an autocomplete small project

Tags: ajax, autocomplete

I am not experienced in this field.

I have a database that contains a table with customer names. For example CUSTOMER_T contains
"customer1", "Nick", "Test", etc...I have a web server connected with the DB and let's say a method to get the "customer names". Also I have a small WEB GUI with a textbox, where the customer types a string and invokes the get method that returns the database results.

I want to enhance this functionality with an auto-complete feature, like google suggest. What do I need to install in the server and in the GUI? Please note that the list of customers is dynamic.

Does the server need a special capability - library?
Does the client need a special capability - library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User JQuery, JQuery UI, and the JQuery UI autocomplete plugin. Start at the [autocomplete plugin page](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax for autocomplete and as just a query to bring back data in for the textfield